# Why does this code going through infinite?

Tags: python, loops

Why the code at the below making infinite loops?
The first return is 9
It is not equal to 10 anymore.
I can't get it.
Could someone explain it easily?

```
n = 10
while True:
    print(n, end=' ')
    n = n - 1
print('Done!')
```

Comment: Where do you check if `n` is equal to `10`? Also fix your indentation.

Comment: I edited your code and made a guess a proper indentation. `while True:` will never break out of the loop. Did you mean something like `while n > 0:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while True` goes forever, because `True` is always gonna be `True`.

If you want to end the loop when `n` becomes `0`, try:

```
n = 10
while n > 0:
    print(n, end=' ')
    n = n - 1
    print('Done!')
```

Output:

```
10 Done!
9 Done!
8 Done!
7 Done!
6 Done!
5 Done!
4 Done!
3 Done!
2 Done!
1 Done!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 10                  # Here you are initializing the variable n as 10
while True:             # Now you are saying, while True (this means forever because you are saying, as long True is true, do this)
    print(n, end=' ') 
    n = n - 1
print('Done!')
```

I believe that you want to validate that n equals to 10, so, the conditional must change:

```
n = 10                  # Here you are initializing the variable n as 10
while n = 10:           # Now you are saying, while n = 10 (this means only once because the loop changes the value of n)
    print(n, end=' ') 
    n = n - 1
print('Done!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using while True without a break statement
Use This

```
n = 10
while n>0:
    print(n, end=' ')
    n = n - 1
    print('Done!')
```

Or

```
n = 10
while True:
    print(n, end=' ')
    n = n - 1
    print('Done!')
    if(n==0):
        break;
```